# Add multiple picture or image into one database record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a system that will allow the user to save a document's digitized copy. Now, is there any other way to allow adding multiple image/picture on one record than creating multiple fields where the attached images' path will be stored?. I worry about what if the image has 100+ attachments, do i need to create 100+ fields also? or is there any other way to use?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a specific table for attachments and link them to their parent record.

If you do this, you can accommodate any number of attachments.

Comment: Hi Johann, do you mean the number of tables will depend on how many records with attachment the system will have? i.e. If have 500 records with attachments then i would have 500 tables also? sorry if i get your comment wrong. Thanks

Comment: One table to store all attachments; each attachment record holds a key to the parent record.

Answer (score 0):

To store images in database:

1. Convert each image into `byte[]`.
2. Store the `byte[]` to `List<byte[]>`
3. Serialize the list and store it in database in blob format.
4. Retrieve images from database:
5. Retrieve the imageList from the database.
6. Deserialize the `List<byte[]>`